# Definition of the probability current

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability

I know that the definition of probability current is given by
\begin{equation}
 J\sim \psi^*\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}-\psi \frac{\partial \psi^*}{\partial x}
\end{equation}
However, some [papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.01807) are using this definition:

\begin{equation}
 J\sim \psi^*\frac{\partial H}{\partial k_x}\psi
\end{equation}
where $H$ is the Hamiltonian of the system and $k_x$ is the wavevector. So, how can I understand that these two are equivalent, and is it possible to derive the second one, I mean where does it come from?

**update**

this question is also related to this [one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/537009/quantum-mechanics-probability-current-density-in-terms-of-velocity-vs-in-terms) where I think we might have a close answer.

Comment: The fisrt formula applies only to non-relativistic Hamiltonians.  The Weyl equation is "relativistic" (although with a different speed of "light").

Comment: @mikestone, to my knowledge for the relativistic case it is given by $J\sim \psi^*\sigma_x \psi$, where $\psi$ is now a spinor and $\sigma_x$ is the Pauli matrix

Comment: Is not $\partial H/\partial k_x=\sigma_x$ for the Weyl Hamiltonian? I Think that this is what your papers are saying...

Comment: @mikestone, No, it is not as you can see from Eq. 15 in the paper, or do I miss somthing?

Comment: If they were using the usual Weyl hamiltonian it would be $\sigma_x$. In general the current is given by the functional derivative of the Hamiltonian wrt to the gauge field $A_i$, but in a plane-wave Bloch state $A$ appears as $k+A$, so  it's also writable as a derivaive wrt $k$.

Comment: It might, or might not, be helpful to consider that $\partial E /\partial p$ is a velocity, both in the non relativistic, and the relativistic case, so the bilinear involved is a type of a current in a continuity equation.

Comment: Notice that if $H \sim k_x (\overleftarrow{\partial_x}-\overrightarrow{\partial_x})$ then the two expressions coincide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I get it and would like to share in case any additional input.
So in general the probability current can be written as

\begin{equation}
 J=\frac{-ie\hbar}{2m} [\psi^*(\nabla\psi)-(\nabla\psi^*)\psi]
\end{equation}
knowing that the momentum operator is $\bf p=-i\hbar\nabla$,  we get

\begin{equation}
 J=\frac{e}{2m} [\psi^*(\bf p\psi)+(\bf p\psi^*)\psi]=\frac{e}{m}Re[\psi^*(p\psi)]
\end{equation}
Now, we can recall that velocity operator  $\bf{v}$ can be written with respect to $\bf p$ as ${\bf{v}}=\bf{p}/m$, yeilding

\begin{equation}
 J=eRe[\psi^*(\bf v\psi)]
\end{equation}

and since $\bf v\sim\frac{\partial H}{\partial k}$ we get the desired form of probability current

\begin{equation}
 J\sim eRe[\psi^*(\bf \frac{\partial H}{\partial k}\psi)]
\end{equation}